# Yogic/Tantra practice providing ability to control body temperature

Tags: yoga, tantra, siddhi, yogi

Tony Buzan in his book **Make the Most of Your Mind** [relates the story](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZIDIoc30Z6sC&pg=PA29&lpg=PA29) of an Indian Yogi, Swami Rama, who in a lab experiment was able to willfully change the temperature of a spot on his right hand. What specific yogic/tantra practice would help do this feat? Here is the relevant excerpt from this book:

> Then in March 1970, an Indian yogi, Swami Rama, visited the Menninger Foundation in Topeka, Kansas, where researchers were doing some exploratory work in the field of one of mankind's fondest dreams: the control of the body with the mind. In a series of experiments, Swami Rama was wired for brain waves, respiration, skin potential, skin resistance, heart behavior, blood flow in the hands, and temperature. While he was thus "wired up" he caused two areas a couple of inches apart on his right hand to change temperature in *opposite* directions. The rate of the temperature change was about 4° Fahrenheit per minute, and he was able to maintain the change until there was a temperature difference of 10°.
>
> Swami Rama also demonstrated that he could "stop his heart" from  pumping blood around his body. It was assumed by the researchers, Alyce Green, Thelma Green, and Dale Walters, that his heart would actually stop beating. What happened instead was that his heart began to fire at about three hundred beats a minute, without blood either filling the chambers properly or the valves working properly.

Comment: A frozen iguana continues to live and when thawed moved  again normally ( newspaper report).

Comment: One such Yogi stopped breath for minutes together.  It is difficult to explain yogic feats, in my view, with logic or science

Comment: Such yogic techniques are to be learnt from a capable guru and not to be tried by reading here n there for such acts can turn out to be death threatening.

Comment: @Narasimham, I'm not clear on what that newspaper on the frozen iguana has to do with my question

Comment: @srimannarayanakv ji, you have a point, however I'm simply seeking the name of the yogic technique used to accomplish this feat, not a scientific rationale for it

Comment: @Just_Do_It, indeed it would be hazardous for a neophyte to undertake such a technique without the supervision of a capable guru however all I am seeking is the name and a brief description of the technique, not step-by-step instructions

Comment: Frozen iguana ? What ?

Answer (score 3):

Bodily functions can be brought under control, under highest form of Yogic techniques.

---

The following is an excerpt from the famous book by Dr. Paul Brunton "A search in Secret India".

The author met an yoga expert by name Brama in Madras (now Chennai).  Brama demonstrates that heart beat/pulse can be stopped.

> "You can control the working of your heart?" I exclaim  in surprise.
>
> "My **self-acting organs, the heart, the stomach and the  kidney, have
>   been brought to some degree of obedience**," he  answers quietly,
>   without a trace of boastfulness.
>
> "How do you do that?"
>
> "**One gains the power by practising certain combinations of  posture,
>   breathing and will-power exercises. Of course, they  belong to the
>   advanced degrees of Yoga.** They are so difficult  that few persons can
>   ever do them. Through these practices  I have conquered somewhat the
>   muscles which work the heart;  and through the heart muscles, I have
>   been able to go on and  conquer the other organs."
>
> "This is indeed extraordinary!"
>
> "You think so? Place your hand upon my chest, just  over the heart,
>   and keep it there." With that, Brama  changes his position, takes up a
>   curious posture, and closes  his eyes.
>
> I obey his command and then wait patiently to see what is  going to
>   happen. For some minutes he remains as steady as  a rock, and almost
>   as motionless. **Then the beating of his heart  begins to diminish
>   gradually**. I am startled to feel it become  slower and slower. A
>   thrill of eerieness spreads over my nerves  as I distinctly feel **his
>   heart completely stop its rhythmic  functioning**. The pause lasts for
>   about seven anxious seconds.

Thereafter, Brama demonstrated that pulse can be stopped.

> As if in answer to my unspoken thought, Brama says:
>
> "It is nothing compared with what my master can achieve.  Sever one of
>   his arteries, and he is able to control the flow of  blood; yes, even
>   to stop it! I, too, **have brought my blood  under some measure of
>   control**, but I cannot do that."
>
> " Can you show me that control? "
>
> He requests me to take his wrist and grip it where I can feel  the
>   flow of blood through his artery. I do so.
>
> Within two or three minutes I become aware that the curious  rhythm
>   which beats under my thumb is lessening. ***Soon it  comes to a definite
>   halt. Brama has brought his pulse to a  stop***!
>
> I anxiously await the resumption of circulation in his artery.  A
>   minute passes but nothing occurs. A second minute, during  which I am
>   acutely conscious of each second, likewise ticks  itself away in my
>   watch. The third minute is equally fruitless.  Not until half-way
>   through the fourth minute do I become  conscious of a faint return to
>   activity within the artery. The  tension is relieved. **Before long, the
>   pulse beats at its normal  rate.**

Comment: upvoted. I would like to know more about what specific techniques are in play here

Comment: I am reproducing the highlighted portion from my answer again - "One gains the power by practising certain combinations of posture, breathing and will-power exercises. Of course, they belong to the advanced degrees of Yoga".  The yoga expert Brama did not disclose it completely. @VidyutDantara